# Finding eigenvectors of a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a $2\times 2$ symbolic matrix for which I want to compute the eigenvalues. It is given as:

```
Clear[a, b, m]
m={{a, b}, {b, -a}}
```

and it spits out the eigensystem as

```
eigs = Eigensystem[m]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 -\sqrt{a^2+b^2} & \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\
 \left\{-\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}{b},1\right\} & \left\{-\frac{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}{b},1\right\} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Although this is expected I have an issue. What I want to do is be able to send $b$ to $0$ after finding the eigenvectors, but given how it is that doesn't work for me. What can I do to enforce this assumption into the code?

Comment: With `b=0` you will encounter infinity. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not at all no, thats why I was hoping something was wrong.

Comment: Set `b` to zero prior to calculating the `Eigensystem`, i.e., `m = {{a, 0}, {0, -a}}; Eigensystem[m]` evaluates to `{{-a, a}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}}`

Comment: Right and that’s fine, but I don’t want b to initially be 0. I want to turn b off after some time if that makes sense.

Comment: In the symbolic case, eigenvectors are (usually) normalized so that one of the components is $1$. So, take the common denominator of all the other components, and multiply the eigenvector with that,

Comment: Right so in both eigenvectors the common denominator would just be b, so multiply both eigenvectors by that and then I have what I need, but won't that affect the eigenvalues too?

Comment: You recall that if $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of the matrix $\mathbf A$, then $c\mathbf v$ is also an eigenvector for any $c\ne 0$, yes?

Comment: Yes that is true.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one, not particularly sophisticated, approach using [Normalize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normalize.html). You could use

```
evs = Map[Normalize,Eigenvectors[{{a,b},{b,-a}}]];
```

to get normalized eigenvectors, meaning eigenvectors of length 1. The normalization gives complicated expressions, which explains why normalization is not the default for symbolic matrices. Assuming your `a` and `b` are real, you can simplify a bit using

```
evs = Simplify[evs,Assumptions->Element[a|b,Reals]];
```

With normalized eigenvectors, you can now try to take the limit:

```
Limit[evs,b->0]
```

Turns out that this fails. However, any one of the following will work:

```
Limit[evs,b->0,Direction->"FromAbove",Assumptions->{a>0}]
Limit[evs,b->0,Direction->"FromBelow",Assumptions->{a>0}]
Limit[evs,b->0,Direction->"FromAbove",Assumptions->{a<0}]
Limit[evs,b->0,Direction->"FromBelow",Assumptions->{a<0}]
```

The reason why one has to provide this more detailed information to `Limit` has to do with the fact that normalization does not fix eigenvectors uniquely, even in cases where all eigenvalues are real and distinct and all eigenvectors real, since for example the sign remains ambiguous.

**Related:** See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116123) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43124), your matrix appears in both.

Comment: Thank you for this! However I am assuming that my $a,b$ are complex

Comment: Tangential remark about the complex case: For every $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ your matrix fixes a canonical splitting of $\mathbb{C}^2$ into an unordered direct sum of two 1-dim subspaces, namely the eigenspaces. Actually this is only for $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ so that the eigenvalues are distinct, so one must cut out the two lines $a=ib$ and $a=-ib$. If you track how the 1-dim eigenspaces change as you walk once around say the line $a=ib$, you will see that the two eigenspaces "exchange". This is just an attempt to give some geometric picture, in the complex case, to the square roots that one is seeing.